# Add data to a div which contains specific data and is among several div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of several div tags, and some text with an url within each div. Something like (looking for the 4th div with "123" in url):

```
<div><a href="example.com/8564rg/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/hz534f/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/i9dj45/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/aaa123/index.html">Text added here</a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/5drs37/index.html"></a></div>
```

How could it be possible to identify a specific div (for example the one, which url has the string "123" in it) and to inject some html (e.g. "Text added here") in this div?

Comment: Grab all: `const divs = parent.querySelectorAll("div a");` Now iterate over them using for instance `.forEach()`, grab `this.href`, use basic "does haystack contain need" string commands, then use `this.textContent = "whatever"`. Just do what everybody does: break it down into parts, google them, implement the building blocks.

Comment: Are you looking to 'inject' into the `div` or the `a`?

Comment: Thanks to all for your so fast answers! Incredible. @Moob: actually, I want to try both to test the code, but had no clue how to do it. But in the `a` will be fine.

Comment: Ok, I tested all versions from all of you and understand well the approach. Thanks a lot. But for some reason, none of them succeed to add the text in the `a` tag. Any idea why that? And just curious: would a div injection be fundamentally different?

Comment: Moob has answered this point below: the code must be at the end of the DOM otherwise the elements are not yet loaded when it executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) (contains).

`[attr*=value]`

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

**Demo:**

```js
var el = document.querySelector('a[href*="123"]');
el.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'New Text added');
```

```html
<div><a href="example.com/8564rg/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/hz534f/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/i9dj45/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/aaa123/index.html">Text added here</a></div>
```

Comment: ok, you target directly the `a`. Cool. What about the ";" at the end of the 2 lines, is it missing?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attribute value contains css selector `[attribute*=value]` here is an example:

```js
const textToAdd = "Text added here";
const anchor = document.querySelector("[href*='123']");
anchor.textContent = textToAdd;
```

```html
<div><a href="example.com/8564rg/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/hz534f/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/i9dj45/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/aaa123/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/5drs37/index.html"></a></div>
```

Comment: thanks, I see how you proceed and this variation is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with CSS *or* JS using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
document.querySelector('a[href*="/5drs37/"]').textContent = "Text added here via JS";
```

```css
a[href*="/aaa123/"]:after {
content: "Text added here via CSS";
}
```

```html
<div><a href="example.com/8564rg/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/hz534f/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/i9dj45/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/aaa123/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/5drs37/index.html"></a></div>
```

Comment: ok, so here you target directly the `a` and don't care about the div. Very nice, thanks!

Comment: The CSS code works, but I can't succeed with the JS code. Do I miss something? The JS code in a script Tag in the head tag does not react. But the CSS yes.

Comment: @Sam77 with the script in the head `document.querySelector` won't find any matching element because those elements don't exist in the DOM yet. Put the script at the bottom of the page before the `</body>` OR if you need it in the `head` wrap the script in a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) listener

Comment: of course! I had forgotten this point. Now I got it to work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. first you put all div in a div container and set a id for it.
2. write foreach loop for every div in div container.
3. in foreach loop get first child or find tag a and get href it.

   ```
   $('#div-container').find('div').each(function(){
     url = this.firstChild.href;
     if(url.includes('534')) {
       this.firstChild.text = "some text"
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: yeah, the loop is a very good idea. I must try this too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you mean such div container like this?

`<div class="div-container">
<div><a href="example.com/8564rg/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/hz534f/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/i9dj45/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/aaa123/index.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="example.com/5drs37/index.html"></a></div>
</div>`

Comment: @Sam77 yes, is better set id instead of class